# Aggregation in MongoDB to get 1 array from a list

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregate-functions, nosql-aggregation

I just started to learn NoSQL. I have a table Orders, which contains a field with the type array - books inside which a field with the type string - name. I want to get the book which is the least in Orders.
So far, I was only able to display the number of equal Orders with books:

```
db.Orders.aggregate([ { $group: { _id: "$books.name", count: { $sum: 1 } } ])
```

And how to aggregate all books into 1 array of all books - I don't understand

I have:

```
[
    {"books":[{"name":"A"}]},
    {"books":[{"name":"A"}]},
    {"books":[{"name":"A"}, {"name": "B"}, {"name": "C"}]},
    {"books":[{"name": "C"}]}
]
```

I wait:

```
[
    {"_id": 'A', "count": 3 },
    {"_id": 'B', "count": 1 },
    {"_id": 'C', "count": 2 }
]
```

I take:

```
[
    {"_id":[{"name":"A"}], count:2},
    {"_id":[{"name":"A"}, {"name": "B"}, {"name": "C"}], count:1},
    {"_id":[{"name": "C"}], count:1}
]
```

Comment: Better provide the sample json documents and the expected result.

Comment: @ray Yes, that's right. I added to my question

Comment: What is the meaning of **I wait** and **I take**? Is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/N3WYvR2VJyM) what you are looking for?

Comment: I'm interpreting it as "want" and "will settle for", which your aggregation satisfies the latter. I think satisfying the former would be done by prepending an `$unwind` to the pipeline in the question.

Comment: I got the result I expected. Can you please also tell me how I can get a minimum count out of this? Now request: db.Orders.aggregate([ {$unwind : "$books" }, { $group: { _id: "$books.name", count: { $sum: 1 } } ])

Comment: Basically just answered the opposite question in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74034288/get-maximum-value-from-mongodb-aggregation-query#comment130720966_74034288), so one approach is to `$sort` by the `count` and then `$limit: 1`

Comment: If there are 2-3-4 identical values in the sample, the limit does not fit